# Distribution of auxiliary verb over infinitives

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, repetition, coordinating-conjunctions

I have a doubt regarding the use of auxiliary verb. When we use an auxiliary verb in a sentence , and suppose it does two tasks and we join them using ,say, 'and' , Is there a need for us to repeat the verb after 'and'.
For instance, Say the sentences are :

1. Don't pity him .
2. Don't cut him some slack.

So is it sufficient to say , Don't pity him and cut him some slack. Does this convey the same meaning as the above two sentences jointly do? The main point is whether repetition of 'don't' is redundant.

If it conveys the same meaning, does the same apply apply for all other auxiliary verbs like have , do etc. I mean whether there is any need to repeat the verb again if we have a conjunction joining two sentences. (any conjunction).
I have seen some questions where it has been asked specifically for some verbs , but I would like to know  the general idea about the usage.

Comment: Not every conjunction works in every situation.  Neither does every adjective.  Consider these natural alternatives: "Don't pity him and don't cut him any slack." "Don't pity him or cut him any slack."

Comment: 'Don't pity him and cut him some slack' has a consequential meaning: 'Don't cut him some slack because you've felt pity for him'. There isn't really an alternative in this case, but ambiguous situations _could_ arise.